# How do you create a new window with a component in angular, and be able to call functions from parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my project i have some tabs where one of them is a Here Map element, i've put in it own component and use in my main view. I want to be able to use this component in a new window instead, but be able to call functions from the parent component. How do i achieve this?

I've tried a couple of solutions, and so far this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-etturt is the closest to my solution, but i can't reference functions in the component and it becomes undefined. The component has a Promise Function im using to init the map.

````
this.hereMaps
        .loadScript()
        .then(() => {
          `//do something when ready
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          throw err;
        });```

I want to be able to use this function, and other functions like the geocoder.
````

Comment: Does it need to be a new browser window object? Or could you put it in a named `router-outlet` and style it as a popup?

Comment: I only need to be able to move the window and resize as i want, doesn't need to be a new browser window object if this is possible without?

Comment: I've never been able to successfully use the CDK. It's **extremely** complicated IME. Have you looked at WindowComponent? If you need a true new window object then I would learn the CDK deeply or get help with it. Or build your own modal popup in a named router-outlet with handles and draggability. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Thank you anyways, i will return with the solution unless anyone beats me to it.